# How to see the relation type in django diagram?

Tags: django, dot

My django model contains many-to-many, foreign-key and other types of relations, yet I'm unable to see that relations in the diagram?

```bash
./manage.py graph_models crm \
--layout=dot \
--arrow-shape normal \
--disable-abstract-fields \
--exclude-models BaseModel \
--disable-fields \
-o crm_diagram.png \
```

What must I do in order to see edge labels showing e.g. **One-to-one**, **many-to-many**, **one-to-many** etc.?

pygraphviz is installed

Example of what I'm looking for:
[image: example]